How to quantify the "degree of convergence" so some number?
This might be a slightly silly question but let's say I have a finite sequence of $k$ numbers which might or might not converge to some constant value if $k$ were allowed to go to infinity. I'm only interested in cases where the sequence converges to either 0 or 1. The sequence might approach 1 from below or it might oscillate around 1 - and the same for 0. There will also be unpredictable pattern of noise which cannot be assumed to be normal.
Assuming that the sequence does converge to 0 or 1 what would be the best way to summarise "to what extent it converges" to 0 in a single number then do the same for 1 finally comparing the two numbers? I realise that these might be very rough estimates but I am just wondering if there is perhaps some clever method that would be applicable here.

How might we infer the slightest bit of information about the limit behaviour of an infinite sequence if all we have is the first few terms?

@HagenvonEitzen Yeah I realise all this isn't very rigorous but I am simply wondering if some rough approximation can be wangled out of the numbers  - I will always have no less than 60 terms and the convergence if there is any at all - and my question assumes there is - should be easily noticeable on a graph.

Take an example of $f(n)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k\left(1-\frac1n\right)^{2^k}$. The initial terms (rounded) $0, 0.309, 0.382, 0.414, 0.429, 0.440, 0.449, 0.456, 0.463, 0.468, \ldots$ etc. look as if they may be converging towards something close to $0.5$, but it does not converge.

@Henry This is an interesting example  -thanks. My question is precisely this- even if it might be a bit silly - to find a way to quantify the "looks like it might converge" property of a sequence, never mind if it is actually true or not.

Basically, the answer is no.
The problem is that the limiting behaviour of a sequence is to some extent independent of the behaviour of any finite collection of its starting terms. This is because limits are defined in a way that essentially says that you can ignore what happens at the start, and just wait until it starts demonstrating its limiting behaviour to work out what's going to happen.
More formally, we say that a sequence $a_n$ has a limit $L$ as $n$ goes to infinity if, for any positive value $\varepsilon$, we can find a number $N$ such that if $n \geq N$ then $|a_n - L| < \varepsilon$. In other words, if you cut off the first $N - 1$ terms then whatever's left will be close to $L$. Similarly, we say $a_n$ diverges to infinity if for every positive value $M$ we can find a number $N$ such that if $n \geq N$ then $a_n > M$, i.e. if we cut off the first $N - 1$ terms then the whole sequence is big.
If you know something about the source of your sequence and you're using those initial values to estimate something about it, then that might be a different matter. For example, if you have something like a logistic growth model where $a_{n + 1} = \lambda a_n (1 - a_n)$ and you're trying to find the value of $\lambda$, then you can calculate that directly from just two consecutive values of the sequence and from there you can determine whether the sequence is going to converge or diverge.
